# How to explicitly name the count column generated by the .N function?

Tags: r, group-by, data.table

I want to group-by a data table by an id column and then count how many times each id occurs. This can be done as follows:

```
dt <- data.table(id =  c(1, 1, 2))
dt_by_id <- dt[, .N, by = id] 

dt_by_id
   id N
1:  1 2
2:  2 1
```

That's pretty fine, but I want the N-column to have a different name (e. g. `count`). In the help it says:

> .N is an integer, length 1, containing the number of rows in the group. This may be useful when the column names are not known in
>   advance and for convenience generally. When grouping by i, .N is the
>   number of rows in x matched to, for each row of i, regardless of
>   whether nomatch is NA or 0. It is renamed to N (no dot) in the result
>   (otherwise a column called ".N" could conflict with the .N variable,
>   see FAQ 4.6 for more details and example), unless it is explicitly
>   named; ... .

How to "explicitly name" the N-column when creating the `dt_by_id` data table? (I know how to rename it afterwards.) I tried

```
dt_by_id <- dt[, count = .N, by = id]
```

but this led to

```
Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , count = .N, by = id) : 
  unused argument (count = .N)
```

Comment: You have to list the output of your calculation if you want to give your own name: `dt[, .(count=.N), by = id] `. This is similar to `dt[, list(count=.N), by = id]`, if you prefer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to list the output of your calculation if you want to give your own name:

`dt[, .(count=.N), by = id]`

This is identical to `dt[, list(count=.N), by = id]`, if you prefer; `.` is an alias for `list` here.

Comment: Maybe worth noting: the same can be done with columns for .GRP and .I.

Answer (score 1):

If we have already named it, then use `setnames`

```
setnames(dt_by_id, "N", 'count')
```

---

or using `rename`

```
library(dplyr)
dt_by_id %>%
   rename(count = N)
#  id count
#1:  1     2
#2:  2     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr::count (x, name= "new column" )` will replace the default column name `n` with a new name.

```
dt <- data.frame(id =  c(1, 1, 2))
dt %>%
   dplyr:: count(id, name = 'ID')
```

Comment: @GertArnold sorry I wasn't familiar with commenting, I was searching for the same and ended up here, but the answer wasn't here, kept searching and when I found it thought to respond. Next time I comment, I will make sure to give enough details.

Comment: The question was about doing this with data.table, not dplyr. You're answering a question about a different count operation